# Memory addition due to variable is initialisation in a while loop

Tags: c, visual-c++

Eg:

```
 int i=0;
 while (i<10000)
 {
   int j;
   i++;
 }
```

Will `j` take 10000 different memory locations or it will destroy and construct in the same or     one specific memory location?

Comment: Most likely, `j` will be completely optimized away. It's quite possible that the whole loop will be replaced with `i = 10000;`

Comment: The compiler is allowed to generate any code at all, so long as the observable behaviour of the program matches the un-optimized version. "observable behaviour" is defined as calls to library functions and accesses of volatile variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 scenarios:

The whole loop will be optimized away and the code actually generated by the compiler will just be the equivalent of

```
int i = 10000 ;
```

or

The compiler will not optimize the while loop and j will be "created" 10000 times. I put "created" between quotes because `j` is actually not created neither is it deleted, it just exists and yes it will normally always be in the same memory location unless you have a very unusual c compiler.

You can check this by putting `printf ("%p\n", &j) ;` inside the loop. This prints the memory address of the `j` variable.

Comment: Using the variable might make the compiler behave differently... It's not a good idea to infer anything with variables memory location.

Comment: But when you print it's address you force the compiler to put it in a memory location. Check the assembler instructions generated to investigate the generated code when compiled with optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

j will be placed on the stack. This means it will be at the same place each time.

If j is not a simple type (such as int) but a complex class which allocates memory, its constructor will be called 10000 times and memory allocated 10000 times. But the class members themselves will stay on the stack at the same location.